# SQL Server: Is there a way to check what is the resulting data type of implicit conversion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, types

Is there a way to check what is the resulting data type of implicit conversion? Or do I simply have to know it based on data types joining the arithmetic operation?

```
declare @i as int
set @i = 3
select @i  / 9.0 as returning_numeric
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the expression is `numeric (17,6)`. To see this

```
DECLARE @i  INT, @v SQL_VARIANT

SET @i = 3
SET @v = @i  / 9.0

SELECT
    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'BaseType') AS VARCHAR(30)) AS BaseType,
    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'Precision') AS INT) AS Precision,
    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'Scale') AS INT) AS Scale
```

Returns

```
BaseType   Precision   Scale
---------- ----------- -----------
numeric    17          6
```

### Edit:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.0, 'BaseType'),
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.0, 'Precision'),
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.0, 'Scale')
```

So the literal `9.0` is treated as `numeric(2,1)` (Can be seen from the query above)

`@i` is `numeric(10,0)` (as per [Mikael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606689/sql-server-is-there-a-way-to-check-what-is-the-resulting-data-type-of-implicit-c/5607814#5607814))

The rules that govern why `numeric(10,0)`/`numeric(2,1)` gives `numeric (17,6)` [are covered here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

```
Operation:        e1 / e2
Result precision: p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
Result scale:     max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

Substituting the relevant values in gives

```
10 - 0 + 1 + max(6, 0 + 2 + 1)  = 17
max(6, 0 + 2 + 1)               =  6
```

Answer (score 2):

The implicit conversion done here is on `@i` to numeric(10,0). You can modify your statement  and look at the execution plan.

```
declare @i int

set @i = 3
select @i  / 9.0
from (select 1) as x(x)
```

Extract from execution plan

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(10,0),[@i],0)/(9.0)">
```

However, the resulting data type is `numeric(17,6)` as Martin showed in his answer and that is not shown in the execution plan.